# document.formname.checkbox[0].checked versus document.getElementById('checkbox').checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

In Javascript, I usually use the syntax`document.formname.checkbox[0].checked`, but I notice that almost everyone else uses `document.getElementById('checkboxid').checked`. My apologies if this seems a silly question, but I'm trying to find out if my preferred syntax has been deprecated, or do others simply use what is more convenient?

Comment: I see that the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html) describes the `document.forms` collection. I didn't see anything about getting the form directly on the `document` object itself, but that doesn't mean it isn't there. I'd stick to what you can find in the spec.

Comment: @squint–forms have been available as named properties of the *document* object forever, HTML5 is not going to deprecate it. see [*getter object (DOMString name)*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-nameditem)

Comment: @RobG: I'd still stick to the spec, but that's my opinion. If it's not in the spec in the first place, I don't think they'd need to deprecate it.

Comment: @squint—it's in the spec, added link to comment.

Comment: Ah, there it is. Thanks @RobG. Though it includes more than just forms. I'd prefer `document.forms`, but that's me.

Comment: @squint—yes, using ID for forms has been preferred for a long time. [*HTML 4 discouraged the use of name on forms*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-name-FORM), to no effect. It has the usual issue of possible clashes with other named properties of a document and the name attribute itself isn't required to be unique.

Comment: `@RobG` that's a Working Draft (WD). Where's the W3C Recommendation (REC)?

Comment: @PHPglue http://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#dom-document-namedItem-which

Comment: Thank  You. Please use REC as your standard.

Answer (score 0):

What each means:

## `document.formname.checkbox[0].checked`

This uses the form's and the element's `name=` attribute to select the element you want. It's good because sometimes you don't want to dirty your markup with IDs everywhere, and you'd prefer to use names, which are something most forms has (because default submission uses names as keys).

The potential problems with that is that it's a bit verbose, and might not very readable.

## `document.getElementById('checkboxId').checked`

This has the simplicity of just plugging an ID and getting the correct element, but then to get any element in the form, it must also have an ID, which can be pretty annoying.

---

### `document.querySelectorAll('#myForm input[type=checkbox]')[0].checked`

Here's an alternative solution, which uses CSS selectors and `document.querySelectorAll()`, I feel that it's more readable, especially for people who are more proficient in CSS than in JavaScript.

---

Which of those is better? Depends on your particular use case and preference. I like to use querySelector and querySelectorAll, especially if I already have the form DOM object in a variable:

```
myForm.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').checked;
```

It's up to you.

Answer (score -1):

`getElementById` is preferred. Consider a webpage with the following contents:

`<div id="x"></div>`

You can access your div `x` in javascript with just `console.log(x)`.

Now consider if you had `var x = 5` defined in the global context. Well, now you can't use `x` to access your div before it now has a value of just `5`.

`getElementById` is preferred because you don't have the potential to overwrite your selector with a variable for something else.

Comment: He's not asking about accessing it as a global variable. He's doing it from the `document` object, so there's no conflict with local variables.

Comment: @squint ah ok, well to be fair my response is still true if you're worried about a collision between your global variables and `Object.keys(document)`

Comment: True. I mean `Object.keys(document)` would be unusual, but generally I don't like using nodes as collections. There are plenty of other properties on `document` that could potentially conflict.

Answer (score -1):

`document.formname.checkbox[0].checked` might not actually work on all Browsers. `document.forms[0].elements` and `document.formName` is standardized, as is `document.getElementById()`

Comment: If it doesn't "work", then the browser is not compliant with HTML5 (or even HTML 4).

Comment: Show me the docs for `document.formName.checkbox` Array like Object please.